# Sum of products of Fibonacci numbers and combination values.

Tags: combinations, fibonacci-numbers

I'm a high school teacher and students had to see the pattern I have below but they didn't have to prove it. However, an intrepid student asked me to prove it and I am stumped. I scoured the internet but I couldn't find any help. Please help me get started! The identity is below. F<sub>0</sub>=0, F<sub>1</sub>=1, F<sub>2</sub>=1, F<sub>3</sub>=2, ..., F<sub>n</sub>=nth Fibonacci number.

(<sub>n</sub>C<sub>0</sub>)(F<sub>k</sub>)+(<sub>n</sub>C<sub>1</sub>)(F<sub>k+1</sub>)+(<sub>n</sub>C<sub>2</sub>)(F<sub>k+2</sub>)+...+(<sub>n</sub>C<sub>n</sub>)(F<sub>k+n</sub>) = F<sub>k+2n</sub>

Comment: my first thought is about how the rows of pascals triangle sum to $2^n$ on row n.

Answer (score 6):

If $M$ is the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$, we have $M^n = \pmatrix{F_{n+1} & F_n\cr F_n & F_{n-1}}$ (well-known and easy to prove by induction).
Then using the binomial theorem and the fact that $M+I = M^2$,
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n {}_nC_j M^{k+j} =  M^k (M+I)^n = M^{k+2n}$$
and your identity follows by taking the matrix elements.

More prosaically, you can prove your identity by induction, using the fact that
${}_{n+1}C_j = {}_nC_{j-1} + {}_nC_{j}$.

Comment: That is pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

Recall [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for Fibonacci's numbers:

$$F_n = \frac{\alpha^n - \beta^n}{\sqrt{5}}
\quad\text{ where }\quad 
\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \beta = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
Using [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and notice $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of the equation $\lambda^2 = \lambda + 1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{s=0}^n \binom{n}{s}F_{k+s}
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\alpha^k\left(\sum_{s=0}^n \binom{n}{s} \alpha^s\right) - \beta^k\left(\sum_{s=0}^n \binom{n}{s} \beta^s\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\alpha^k(\alpha+1)^n - \beta^k(\beta+1)^n\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\alpha^{k+2n} - \beta^{k+2n}\right]\\
&= F_{k+2n}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Use the two famous [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) relations $~F_{i+1}~=~F_i~+~F_{i-1}~$ [and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle)

$C_{n+1}^{k+1}~=~C_n^k~+~C_n^{k+1}~$ in order to ultimately establish a proof by [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) :

> $$\begin{align}
> F_m
> ~&=~F_{m-1}~+~F_{m-2}
> ~&=~C_1^0~F_{m-1}~+~C_1^1~F_{m-2}
> \qquad\qquad\quad~
> \\\\
> ~&=~\Big(F_{m-2}~+~F_{m-3}\Big)~+~\Big(F_{m-3}~+~F_{m-4}\Big)
> ~&=~C_2^0~F_{m-2}~+~C_2^1~F_{m-3}~+~C_2^2~F_{m-4}
> \\\\
> ~&=~\ldots
> ~&=~\ldots
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
> \end{align}$$

Can you take it from here ?...